# How to exclude node_module folder from build in visual studio 2015 update 3

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-5, single-page-application, node-modules

I'm trying to use Visual Studio as my IDE for developing an ASP.NET MVC 5 SPA with Angular 2.
The problem raises when I try to build the project. It gives me many errors inside `*.d.ts` files.

I created the project using `angular-cli` the command : `ng new project-name`

and here is what the solution explorer looks like :

[image: as you see already I excluded the node_modules folder]

How do I get rid of these errors? I haven't had any problems with using angular 2 in Visual Studio Code

[image: error list panel]

**Update :**

According to your answers I added the following in the `tsconfig.json` file, but it seems it doesn't work

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2016"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "./node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Edit your `tsconfig.json` to exclude the node_modules folder from compiling.

Comment: I've tried that, but it doesn't make change @jessehouwing

Comment: Try hiding the `node_modules` directory in Windows Explorer.

Comment: Already I did it, but it won't work, I think the problem is cause  of using webpack @OmidKamangar

Comment: Removing `"strict": true` in tsconfig.json eliminated similar errors for me.

Comment: excluding node_modules does not work, still compiles a handful of them.  about 4

Comment: Answer is provided below, but for anyone interested in improving performance of VS solution explorer simply set folder `node_modules` as hidden, this will remove it from solution explorer, thus improve the loading times. To solve build issues please see answers below

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you're using the latest Typescript tools for your version of Visual Studio. A colleague of mine had a similar problem, if you've already excluded the node_modules folder in your tsconfig this may be the issue.

For VS 2015: 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593

Comment: For VS 2017- Latest TS: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55258

Comment: For VS 2022, TS 4.6 https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TypeScriptTeam.typescript-46
Also needed to add "exclude" part in tsconfig.json (see answer below)

Answer (score 2):

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "system",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "outFile": "../../built/local/tsc.js",
        "sourceMap": true
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```